# How to map Capslock to CTRL+SHIFT+B?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey, and I'm trying to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

My attempt:

```
Capslock::^+b
return
```

I have done this by right clicking on the AHK window and editing script, which is in `My Documents/Autohotkey.ahk` and overwriting the default script with the code above, and refreshing with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Hopefully, that is also the correct way to execute the AHK change.

Additionally, I don't want my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to be on when I start typing.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking because your script failed to work? Did you try to close and relaunch AHK?

Comment: It did not work. No error either. I have restarted AHK too.

Comment: I just wrote `CapsLock::^+b` in a .AHK file and ran it, then set a Start Menu shortcut to be executed on pressing Ctrl+Shift+B. When I pressed CapsLock the shortcut was executed as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `autohotkey` if properly installed on your system.

Open `notepad.exe` and paste you program into a new blank file.

Save the file then double click on the icon.

Comment: New file worked. Not sure what the difference is between the new file and the default in my documents. Thanks.